# how to send response from server to selected client among multiple connected client?

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing one application using socket programming.Within that, server can connected to multiple client.When server send response massage, it goes to any one of the connected client.but i want to send it to particular selected client.so how  can i achieve it? I am new in socket programming.so please help me to solve it.thanks in advanced

Comment: You can manage the list of connected client on the server endpoint. On recieving the message iterate through the list  and check your rules against the list of client and send the message to desired ones. try this [link](http://yakovfain.com/2014/12/29/pushing-data-to-multiple-websocket-clients-from-a-java-server/) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `serverSocket.accept()` and a client connects to the server, `accept()` method returns a `Socket` object, you communicate with the client through this Socket object.

Everything you have to do is to create a list `List<Socket> myClientSockets`
and after you call `Socket client = serverSocket.accept()` you just have to add `client` object to the `myClientSockets`. Now you are able to choose the client which you want to communicate with.

**Edited:**

Suppose you have something like that

```
List<Socket> myClientSockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();

while(true)
{
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept()
    myClientSockets.add(client);
}
```

Then you can obtain client socket from `myClientSockets` for example by index.

```
Socket obtainedSocket = myClientSockets.get(myIndex); //you choose the index
```

As well you can iterate through the myClientSockets and obtain the client socket that meet your criteria using foreach ( for ) loop.

Then you can get the `OutputStream`

```
OutputStream obtainedSocketOutputStream = obtainedSocket.getOutputStream()
```

Comment: i am new in socket programing ,can u please elaborate how can we choose client from list myClientSocket and send message?and how can we initialize outputstream from socket present in list myClientSocket

Comment: i suggest using map instead of a list. After `serverSocket.accept()` you can read string form socket that contains info about client, and then you put it into map using instructions like: `clients.put(clientId,socketToClient)`.  Or you can create clientsID from info provided by socket- address ip etc. It all depends on what this communication is for.